# Adding permission sets to permission set groups using SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, permission-sets

I'm trying to add a permission set to a permission set group with the following syntax:

```
sfdx force:data:create:record -s PermissionSetGroupMember -v values="PermissionSetId='0PS5x000000amqlGAA' PermissionSetGroupId='0PG5x00000000M1GAI'"
```

I keep getting back:

```
Error (1): The requested resource does not exist
```

Is there a better way to do this with either anonymous apex or SFDX?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **PermissionSetGroupMember** but it's **PermissionSetGroupComponet**
And there is no such parameter called **values**

Try with the below command -

```
sfdx force:data:create:record -s PermissionSetGroupComponet -v "PermissionSetId='0PS5x000000amqlGAA' PermissionSetGroupId='0PG5x00000000M1GAI'"
```

For more information -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm#cli_reference_force_data_record_create